R flag a change in column value
I have the following dataset with 20 million rows. It's data on companies and user by month.
I have created first_app_company, which flags first appeareance of a company in the dataset. The code is as follows
df$first_app_company <- as.numeric(!duplicated(df$Company_id))

Company_id    Customer   Month-Year          first_app_company
    11               X             201501               1
    12               Y             201501               1
    13               Z             201501               1
    13               Q             201501               0
    13               R             201501               0
    14               E             201501               1
    14               W             201501               0 
    15               X             201501               1 
    15               Z             201501               0 
    15               H             201501               0
    15               K             201501               0
    16               Q             201501               0

However, I realised now, that when a company enters my dataset in month M, I would like to flag all rows that match that company name and month M as 1. So my desired output would look like:
(Please note that 201501 is first month in my dataset so all entries will be flagged as 1, but it shows the logic)
Company_id    Customer   Month-Year          first_app_company
11               X             201501               1
12               Y             201501               1
13               Z             201501               1
13               Q             201501               1
13               R             201501               1
14               E             201501               1
14               W             201501               1 
15               X             201501               1 
15               Z             201501               1 
15               H             201501               1
15               K             201501               1
16               Q             201501               1

I am currently trying to figure it out with lead and lag functions from base R, but it is getting a bit confusing. Was hoping someone would point me in the right direction

"Company name" is the numeric Company_id? 11 is the company entering? It seems 12 and 13 are also newly introduced, like shown in your first attempt, why disregarding them now? "Month M" is Month-Year? What should happen when Month-Year changes? Ones all the way down?

At the moment there are 1000 possible ways to get to the output you stated, e.g. df %>% mutate(first_app_company = cumsum(Company_id == 11), .by = Month_Year) but that won't help since it only covers a small subset of the data.

Which case is excluded then? To me it appears you trying to add 1 to 2e7 rows.

Pretty bad example data. Also please make it reproducible.

Does base R have a lag or lead function? I'm aware of those in dplyr or Hmisc, but I thought you usually had to fiddle with indices to get that behavior in base R. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997586/shifting-a-vector

My approach would be to make a smaller data set with just one row per Company-month. Mark first month per Company in that, then join to full data. library(dplyr); df |> left_join(df |> distinct(Company_id, 'Month-Year') |> mutate(first_app = 1 * 'Month-Year' == min('Month-Year'), .by = Company_id))

Here are two ideas: any() and left_join():
library(dplyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~company_id,  ~month_year,
  1,            201501,
  1,            201502,
  2,            201502,
  1,            201503,
  2,            201503,
  3,            201503,
  3,            201503,
  3,            201504,
  4,            201504,
  4,            201504,
  1,            201505,
  2,            201505,
  3,            201505,
  4,            201505
)

any()
data %>% 
  mutate(first_app_company = as.numeric(!duplicated(.$company_id))) %>% 
  mutate(
    first_app_company = as.numeric(any(first_app_company == 1)), 
    .by = c(company_id, month_year)
  )
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#>    company_id month_year first_app_company
#>         <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>
#>  1          1     201501                 1
#>  2          1     201502                 0
#>  3          2     201502                 1
#>  4          1     201503                 0
#>  5          2     201503                 0
#>  6          3     201503                 1
#>  7          3     201503                 1
#>  8          3     201504                 0
#>  9          4     201504                 1
#> 10          4     201504                 1
#> 11          1     201505                 0
#> 12          2     201505                 0
#> 13          3     201505                 0
#> 14          4     201505                 0

left_join()
data %>% 
  left_join(
    data %>%
      distinct(company_id, month_year) %>% 
      mutate(
        first_app_company = as.numeric(month_year == min(month_year)), 
        .by = company_id
      ),
    by = join_by(company_id, month_year)
  )
#> # A tibble: 14 × 3
#>    company_id month_year first_app_company
#>         <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>
#>  1          1     201501                 1
#>  2          1     201502                 0
#>  3          2     201502                 1
#>  4          1     201503                 0
#>  5          2     201503                 0
#>  6          3     201503                 1
#>  7          3     201503                 1
#>  8          3     201504                 0
#>  9          4     201504                 1
#> 10          4     201504                 1
#> 11          1     201505                 0
#> 12          2     201505                 0
#> 13          3     201505                 0
#> 14          4     201505                 0

Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0
